# Limit result nested and get total number rows Laravel 4

Tags: orm, laravel-4, eloquent

i have some trouble limiting the result on a relation and get the original number of the rows. Let's go with my secenario:

I have posts, content of the post and comment. i want select all post and limit to 5 my comments, but i need to know how many comment have that post.

```
$post = Post::with(array('contentPost','commentPost' => function($query){
            $query->take(5);
        }))->where('wall_id','=',$team_info->id)->get();
```

with this relation i limited the comments to 5 it's right! but if i want count all the comments doing

`$post->commentPost->count();`

it show me just 5 comments because i limited it. How can i get the real number of comments even if i limited them?

Answer (score 2):

In your `$post->commentPost->count()` call, you're asking for the `count()` of the results associated with $post.  Naturally, this will always be the actual number of rows provided by your query parameters.

"Do it all in one place" is rarely the answer in development.  Even if you find a way to make it happen, what happens in the future when you need to change this query?  You end up with fragile code, prone to breakage.

Keep your relation as-is, with the 5-post limit.  Run a separate query for the count.